# Set environment path in linux using python script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, unix

I am setting linux os environment variable inside python scripts. Looks like it does not setting properly.

code used:

```
import os
from subprocess import call
squid_server_ip = 1.1.1.1 
os.chdir("somepath")
call(["pwd"])
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH="] = ".:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
print os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] 
call(["./DUModifier","-httpproxy", "{}:3128".format(squid_server_ip)])
```

Output:

```
 somepath
 /export-path
 ./DUModifier: error while loading shared libraries: xBase39.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Manual execution :

```
 cd somepath
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY
 echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 .:.:/export-path
 ./DUModifier -httpproxy 1.1.1.1:3128

  DUModifier Release2.1 2018-01-16T04:07:57-05:00
  Configuration file to modify: xgDeployConfig.xml
  New configurations are:
  Option: httpproxy, value: 1.1.1.1:3128
  Successfully modified config file: xgDeployConfig.xml
```

Can any one please help me to fix

Comment: Thanks for Pointing out I used like os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = ".:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"..Then it works fine

Comment: Unless I misunderstand (which is quite possible), then no, it does *not* work fine: there are multiple problems with this - see the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the environment into the `call()`. Something like this:

```
myenv = {'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': ".:./export-path"}
```

(as a comment points out, you cannot use $LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the value: that's bash syntax; in python, you'd have to use `os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']` to get the current value and then use that when setting up `myenv`). Then use it in the call:

```
call(["./DUModifier","-httpproxy", "{}:3128".format(squid_server_ip)], env=myenv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to use system env variables?
I love to use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dotenv so you can have local **.env** file with defined variables inside, and easy to use in your script :>
Or do you have obligation for using strict system env?

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

> os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH="] = ".:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

You should write:

```
if  os.environ.has_key("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"):
    os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = ".:" + os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]
else:
    os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "."
```

Comment: This is a (relatively) minor problem: the main problem is that the OP wants to call  a program and *pass it a modified environment*.